# Prove that every number $n \geq 12$ is the sum of two composite numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that any natural number greater than or equal to 12 is the sum of two composite numbers.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450930/prove-by-contradiction-that-every-integer-greater-than-11-is-a-sum-of-two-compos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove by contradiction that every integer greater than 11 is a sum of two composite numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450930/prove-by-contradiction-that-every-integer-greater-than-11-is-a-sum-of-two-compos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $n-8$ and $n-9$ cannot be both prime, if $n \geq 12$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Thank You.

Comment: I really thought that would enlight instantly. Maybe $n=(n-8)+8=(n-9)+9$ does.